# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, finding malloc() and free() pairs

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, malloc, free

I am trying to port a Linux program written in C to Windows.

In the original program, they defined a small function which allocates aligned memory. If they want to free it, they just call `free()`. I used `_aligned_malloc()` to allocate but when I want to free it, I also need to use `_aligned_free()`. But I have to find all the calls of the function `free()` which correspond to the aligned allocations. Not all of the allocations are aligned, so I cannot simply replace all the `free()`'s with `_aligned_free()`.

My question is: is there any tool in Visual Studio which can find the `malloc()` / `free()` pairs?

Any advice?

I am also new to Visual Studio.

Comment: Why are you using _aligned_malloc in the first place?

Comment: I will try malloc() only. I have no idea why they do aligned memory allocation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C `maloc()` is guaranteed to return memory aligned for any purpose.

I think you can replace all `_aligned_malloc()` calls with `malloc()` ones. Just drop the alignment parameter ...

```
#define _align_malloc(size, alignment) malloc(size) /* ignore alignment */
```